SwiftUI not observing SwiftData changes
I have an app with the following model:
@Model class TaskList {
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var name: String
    
    // Relationships
    var parentList: TaskList?
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \TaskList.parentList)
    var taskLists: [TaskList]?
        
    init(name: String, parentTaskList: TaskList? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.parentList = parentTaskList
        self.taskLists = []
    }
}

If I run the following test, I get the expected results - Parent has it's taskLists array updated to include the Child list created. I don't explicitly add the child to the parent array - the parentList relationship property on the child causes SwiftData to automatically perform the append into the parent array:
    @Test("TaskList with children with independent saves are in the database")
    func test_savingRootTaskIndependentOfChildren_SavesAllTaskLists() async throws {
        let modelContext = TestHelperUtility.createModelContext(useInMemory: false)
        let parentList = TaskList(name: "Parent")
        
        modelContext.insert(parentList)
        try modelContext.save()
        
        let childList = TaskList(name: "Child")
        childList.parentList = parentList
        modelContext.insert(childList)
        try modelContext.save()
        
        let fetchedResults = try modelContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<TaskList>())
        let fetchedParent = fetchedResults.first(where: { $0.name == "Parent"})
        let fetchedChild = fetchedResults.first(where: { $0.name == "Child" })
        #expect(fetchedResults.count == 2)
        #expect(fetchedParent?.taskLists.count == 1)
        #expect(fetchedChild?.parentList?.name == "Parent")
        #expect(fetchedChild?.parentList?.taskLists.count == 1)
    }

I have a subsequent test that deletes the child and shows the parent array being updated accordingly. With this context in mind, I'm not seeing these relationship updates being observed within SwiftUI. This is an app that reproduces the issue. In this example, I am trying to move "Finance" from under the "Work" parent and into the "Home" list.

To start, the following code is a working example where the behavior does what I expect - it moves the list from one parent to another without any issue. This is done using the native OutlineGroup in SwiftUI.
ContentView
struct ContentView: View {
    @Query(sort: \TaskList.name) var taskLists: [TaskList]
    @State private var selectedList: TaskList?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(taskLists.filter({$0.parentList == nil})) { list in
                    OutlineGroup(list, children: \.taskLists) { list in
                        Text(list.name)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                selectedList = list
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(item: $selectedList, onDismiss: {
                selectedList = nil
            }) { list in
                TaskListEditorScreen(existingList: list)
            }
        }
    }
}

TaskListEditorScreen
struct TaskListEditorScreen: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    @State private var viewModel: TaskListEditorViewModel
    @Bindable var list: TaskList
    
    init(existingList: TaskList) {
        list = existingList
        viewModel = TaskListEditorViewModel(taskList: existingList)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TaskListFormView(viewModel: viewModel)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Button("Cancel") {
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                    
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Button("Save") {
                            list.name = viewModel.name
                            list.parentList = viewModel.parentTaskList
                            try! modelContext.save()
                            
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}


TaskListFormView
struct TaskListFormView: View {
    @Bindable var viewModel: TaskListEditorViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                TextField("Name", text: $viewModel.name)
                
                NavigationLink {
                    TaskListPickerScreen(viewModel: self.viewModel)
                } label: {
                    Text(self.viewModel.parentTaskList?.name ?? "Parent List")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

TaskListPickerScreen
struct TaskListPickerScreen: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Query(filter: #Predicate { $0.parentList == nil }, sort: \TaskList.name)
    private var taskLists: [TaskList]
    
    @Bindable var viewModel: TaskListEditorViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(taskLists) { list in
                OutlineGroup(list, children: \.taskLists) { child in
                    getRowForChild(child)
                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem {
                Button("Clear Parent") {
                    viewModel.parentTaskList = nil
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder func getRowForChild(_ list: TaskList) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Text(list.name)
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            if list.name == viewModel.name {
                return
            }
            
            self.viewModel.parentTaskList = list
            dismiss()
        }
    }
}


TaskListEditorViewModel
@Observable class TaskListEditorViewModel {
    var name: String
    var parentTaskList: TaskList?
    
    init(taskList: TaskList) {
        name = taskList.name
        parentTaskList = taskList.parentList
    }
}

You can setup the following container and seed it with test data to verify that the result is the lists can move between parents and SwiftUI updates it accordingly.
#Preview {
    ContentView()
        .modelContext(DataContainer.preview.dataContainer.mainContext)
}

@MainActor class DataContainer {
    let schemaModels = Schema([ TaskList.self ])
    let dataConfiguration: ModelConfiguration
    
    static let shared = DataContainer()
    static let preview = DataContainer(memoryDB: true)
    
    init(memoryDB: Bool = false) {
        dataConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: memoryDB)
    }
    
    lazy var dataContainer: ModelContainer = {
        do {
            let container = try ModelContainer(for: schemaModels)
            seedData(context: container.mainContext)
            return container
        } catch {
            fatalError("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }()
    
    func seedData(context: ModelContext) {
        let lists = try! context.fetch(FetchDescriptor<TaskList>())
        if lists.count == 0 {
            Task { @MainActor in
                SampleData.taskLists.filter({ $0.parentList == nil }).forEach {
                    context.insert($0)
                }
                
                try! context.save()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SampleData {
    static let taskLists: [TaskList] = {
        let home = TaskList(name: "Home")
        let work = TaskList(name: "Work")
        let remodeling = TaskList(name: "Remodeling", parentTaskList: home)
        let kidsBedroom = TaskList(name: "Kids Room", parentTaskList: remodeling)
        let livingRoom = TaskList(name: "Living Room", parentTaskList: remodeling)
        let management = TaskList(name: "Management", parentTaskList: work)
        let finance = TaskList(name: "Finance", parentTaskList: work)
                
        return [home, work, remodeling, kidsBedroom, livingRoom, management, finance]
    }()
}

However, I need to customize the layout and interaction of each row, including how the indicators are handled. To facilitate this, I replaced the use of OutlineGroup with my own custom views. The following three views make up that component - allowing for parent/child nesting.

Note at face value it may seem like these don't do much else over OutlineGroup. In my real app these are more complicated. It is streamlined for the reproducible example.

struct TaskListRowContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Bindable var taskList: TaskList
    @State var isShowingEditor: Bool = false
    
    init(taskList: TaskList) {
        self.taskList = taskList
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(taskList.name)
        }
        .contextMenu {
            Button("Edit") {
                isShowingEditor = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingEditor) {
            TaskListEditorScreen(existingList: taskList)
        }
    }
}

struct TaskListRowParentView: View {
    @Bindable var taskList: TaskList
    @State private var isExpanded: Bool = true
    
    var children: [TaskList] {
        taskList.taskLists!.sorted(by: { $0.name < $1.name })
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
            ForEach(children) { child in
                if child.taskLists!.isEmpty {
                    TaskListRowContentView(taskList: child)
                } else {
                    TaskListRowParentView(taskList: child)
                }
            }
        } label: {
            TaskListRowContentView(taskList: self.taskList)
        }
    }
}

struct TaskListRowView: View {
    @Bindable var taskList: TaskList
    
    var body: some View {
        if taskList.taskLists!.isEmpty {
            TaskListRowContentView(
                taskList: taskList)
        } else {
            TaskListRowParentView(taskList: taskList)
        }
    }
}

With these views defined, I update my ContentView to use them instead of the OutlineGroup.
List {
    ForEach(taskLists.filter({$0.parentList == nil})) { list in
        TaskListRowView(taskList: list)
    }
}

With this change in place, I start to experience my issue within SwiftUI. I will move the Finance list out of the Work list via the editor and into the Home parent. During debugging, I can verify that the modelContext.save() call I am doing immediately causes both of the parent lists to update. The work.taskLists is reduced by 1 and the home.tasksLists array as increased by 1 as expected. I can kill the app and relaunch and I see the finance list as a child of the Home list. However, I don't see this reflect in real-time. I have to kill the app to see the changes.
If I alter my save code so that it manually updates the parent array - the issue goes away and it works as expected.
ToolbarItem {
    Button("Save") {
        list.name = viewModel.name
        list.parentList = viewModel.parentTaskList
        
        // Manually add to "Home"
        if let newParent = viewModel.parentTaskList {
            newParent.taskLists?.append(list)
        }
        
        try! modelContext.save()
        
        dismiss()
    }
}

This has me confused. When I debug this, I can see that viewModel.parentTaskList.taskLists.count equals 2 (Remodeling, Finance). I can print the contents of the array and both the Remodeling and Finance models are in there as expected. However, the UI doesn't work unless I explicitly call newParent.taskLists?.append(list). The list already exists in the array and yet I must do this in order for SwiftUI to update it's binding.
Why does my explicit append call solve for this? I don't understand how the array was mutated by SwiftData and the observing Views did not get notified of the change. My original approach (not manually updating the arrays) works fine in every unit/integration test I run but I can't get SwiftUI to observe the array changes.
If someone could explain why this is the case and whether or not I'll be required to manually update the arrays going forward I would appreciate it.
I have the full source code available as a Gist for easier copy/paste - it matches the contents of the post.
Edit
One other thing that causes confusion for me is that the Finance list already exists prior to my manually appending it to the parent list array. So, despite my appending it anyway SwiftData is smart enough to not duplicate it. With that being the case, I don't know if it's just replacing what's in there, or saying "nope" and not adding it. If it's not adding it, then what is notifying the observing Views that the data changed?

You can't use @State with a class, it needs to be a struct. @Observable is for model data anyway not view data. Try just removing the "view model" thats what the View struct is for anyway, use State and Binding for dynamic view data.

You can use @State with a class, it is Apple recommended way to create the source of truth.
See Apple official documentations at Create the source of truth for model data, where you have @State private var book = Book() given @Observable class Book: ...

append to the list

Thanks, I read through the linked doc and it appears that I'm using it correctly.  Still unclear why the array isn't notifying observers of a new element added by SwiftData but it does when I re-add it.

Another weird aspect to this is that I don't need to manually remove the model from the old parent - SwiftData does this for me just like the addition... and SwiftUI updates. It seems only the adding isn't being picked up by SwiftUI - SwiftData based removals are. I would expect this behavior to be consistent between both operations.

I am wondering, if you have a parentList property, isn't the taskLists property redundant? The child lists of TaskList are all those that have the TaskList set as their parentList, no? If so, wouldn't eliminating the taskLists array simplify the logic considerably?

It provides me forward navigation of the hierarchy. Another benefit is it provides me with the entire relationship built for binding. Otherwise, I'd have to query for all lists and build the hierarchy myself from a flat list. It works as intended with SwiftData, so that's not an issue. The issue is that SwiftData mutates the array and SwiftUI doesn't know. If I mutate it, it does. OutlineGroup works and my custom views don't which tells me I'm doing the binding wrong someplace but I can't see where or how

Indeed, you shouldn't have to append to the array for the changes to be detected, especially if the list already exists in the array.
If you have to do that, it's likely that the approach used for passing, editing and observing changes to objects is not "proper".
The first thing that intrigued me was the presence of the taskLists property, which seemed redundant given the parentList property. The child lists of a list would be all lists that have that list set as their parentList.
If you have a parentList property AND a taskLists array property, it means you have to manage changes to both every time you update a list's parent. That simply sounds like overkill.
Regarding the taskLists property, you mentioned in the comments:

Otherwise, I'd have to query for all lists and build the hierarchy myself from a flat list. It works as intended with SwiftData, so that's not an issue. The issue is that SwiftData mutates the array and SwiftUI doesn't know.

From the looks of it, it doesn't quite work as intended.
It would be much simpler to architect everything such that in order to change a list's parent you only need to update the parentList property - and have the UI react accordingly. This would reduce complexity and simplify troubleshooting precisely in the kind of scenario you're describing.
In my experience, when there's a need to observe changes to a SwiftData array property, it's very likely additional consideration and configuration will be required depending on the model, especially if it involves multiple/nested levels of objects and arrays.
Because you're using SwiftData models and @Observable class, you can pass around objects without necessarily requiring bindings, since any changes to the object's properties will be observed automatically. As such, I think it's more flexible and intuitive to pass parameters to views instead of relying on a @Bindable in every view.
Regarding querying for all lists, you're already doing so. Actually, you're doing it twice. The "forward" navigation is not really needed when it can be done with a recursive view.
After spending some time attempting to pinpoint the reason your code doesn't react to changes (which could be any of the above points), I ended up making too many changes to keep track of.
Below you find the code with my approach for your use case, which I commented as much as possible for clarity:

import SwiftUI
import SwiftData
import Observation

//SwiftData model
@Model class TaskList {
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var name: String
    
    // Define the parent relationship but don't create a reverse relationship
    @Relationship(inverse: nil) var parentList: TaskList?
    
    init(name: String, parentList: TaskList? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.parentList = parentList
    }
    
}

//Model extension
extension TaskList {
    
    //Function to insert sample list data
    static func insertSampleData(context: ModelContext) {
        
        //Define sample lists (without relationship)
        let home = TaskList(name: "Home")
        let work = TaskList(name: "Work")
        let remodeling = TaskList(name: "Remodeling" )
        let kidsBedroom = TaskList(name: "Kids Room")
        let livingRoom = TaskList(name: "Living Room")
        let management = TaskList(name: "Management")
        let finance = TaskList(name: "Finance")
        
        let sampleLists = [home, work, remodeling, kidsBedroom, livingRoom, management, finance]
        
        // Insert all sample lists
        sampleLists.forEach { context.insert($0) }
        
        // Set up parent-child relationships
        remodeling.parentList = home
        kidsBedroom.parentList = remodeling
        livingRoom.parentList = remodeling
        management.parentList = work
        finance.parentList = work
        
        // Save all changes in one go
        try? context.save()
    }
    
    //Function to delete a list individually or with children
    func delete(includeChildren: Bool = false, in context: ModelContext) {
        // Find all child TaskLists
        let children = self.children(in: context)
        
        for child in children {
            if includeChildren {
                // Recursively delete each child
                child.delete(includeChildren: true, in: context)
            }
            else {
                //Set child's parent to nil
                child.parentList = nil
            }
        }
        
        // Delete the current list
        context.delete(self)
    }
    
    //Function to get a list's children
    func children(in context: ModelContext) -> [TaskList] {
        let parentID = self.id
        
        // Create a FetchDescriptor with a predicate to filter by the parent list
        let fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<TaskList>(
            predicate: #Predicate<TaskList> { list in
                list.parentList?.persistentModelID == parentID
            }
        )
        
        do {
            // Use the FetchDescriptor to perform the fetch
            return try context.fetch(fetchDescriptor)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to fetch children for \(self.name): \(error)")
            return []
        }
    }
}

//Main view
struct TaskListContentView: View {
    
    //Environment values
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    //Bindings
    @Bindable var listObserver: ListEditObserver = ListEditObserver.shared
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            
            TaskListOutline()
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                        Button {
                            DataContainer.preview.resetData(context: DataContainer.preview.dataContainer.mainContext)
                        } label: {
                            //Icon label
                            HStack {
                                Text("Reset")
                                Image(systemName: "arrow.trianglehead.2.counterclockwise.rotate.90")
                                    .imageScale(.small)
                            }
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        .sheet(item: $listObserver.editList, onDismiss: {
            listObserver.selectedList = nil
        }) { list in
            NavigationStack {
                TaskListFormView(list: list)
            }
        }
    }
}

//List tree view
struct TaskListOutline: View {
    
    //Queries
    @Query(sort: \TaskList.name) private var taskLists: [TaskList]
    
    //Environment values
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    //Bindings
    @Bindable var listObserver = ListEditObserver.shared
    
    //State values
    @State private var showDeleteAlert: Bool = false
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            ForEach(taskLists.filter({$0.parentList == nil}), id: \.self) { list in
                TaskListRowView(list: list, taskLists: taskLists)
            }
        }
        
        //Dismiss when a list is selected
        .onChange(of: ListEditObserver.shared.selectedList) { _, list in
            if list != nil {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
        
        //Observe deleteList and show delete confirmation when it changes
        .onChange(of: listObserver.deleteList){ _, list in
            if list != nil {
                showDeleteAlert = true
            }
        }
        
        //Delete confirmation alert
        .alert(
            "Confirm deletion",
            isPresented: $showDeleteAlert,
            presenting: listObserver.deleteList
        ) { list in
            Button("Delete \(list.name) only", role: .destructive) {
                list.delete(in: modelContext)
                try? modelContext.save()
            }
            Button("Delete all", role: .destructive) {
                list.delete(includeChildren: true, in: modelContext)
                try? modelContext.save()
            }
            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {
                // Reset the list to be deleted in the singleton
                listObserver.deleteList = nil
            }
        } message: { list in
            Text("Do you want to delete all lists in \(list.name)?")
        }
    }
}

//List editor
struct TaskListFormView: View {

    //Parameters
    let list: TaskList
    
    //Environment values
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    //State values
    @State private var selectedList: TaskList?
    @State private var listName: String = ""
    @State private var parentList: TaskList?
    
    //Bindings
    @Bindable var listObserver: ListEditObserver = ListEditObserver.shared
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Form {
                
                //Field to edit the list name
                TextField("Name", text: $listName)
                
                //Link to select a parent list
                NavigationLink{
                    TaskListOutline()
                        .environment(\.enableListEdit, false)
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Parent list:")
                            .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                        Text(parentList?.name ?? "None")
                    }
                }
                
                Section {
                    //Button to clear the parent and dismiss
                    Button {
                        list.parentList = nil
                        try? modelContext.save()
                        dismiss()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Clear parent")
                    }
                    
                    //Disable button if list has no parent
                    .disabled(list.parentList == nil)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            
            //Set initial state values
            listName = list.name
            parentList = listObserver.selectedList ?? list.parentList
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                Button("Cancel") {
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
            
            ToolbarItem {
                Button("Save") {
                    list.name = listName
                    list.parentList = parentList
                    
                    try? modelContext.save()
                    listObserver.selectedList = nil
                    
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//List Row
struct TaskListRowView: View {
    
    //Parameters
    let list: TaskList
    let taskLists: [TaskList]
    
    //Environment values
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    //Helper function to check if the list has any children
    private func hasChildren(_ list: TaskList) -> Bool {
        return taskLists.contains { $0.parentList == list }
    }
    
    //State values
    @State private var isExpanded: Bool = true
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        //Show lists that are not the one being edited (so it can't be selected as its own parent)
        if list != ListEditObserver.shared.editList {
            
            if hasChildren(list) {
                
                //Show a disclosure group if the list has children
                DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
                    
                    // Display sub-TaskLists by filtering
                    ForEach(taskLists.filter{ $0.parentList == list }) { childList in
                        TaskListRowView(list: childList, taskLists: taskLists)
                    }
                    
                } label: {
                    TaskListNameLabel(list: list)
                }
                
            } else {
                
                //Show just the list name without an arrow if no children
                TaskListNameLabel(list: list)
            }
        }
    }
}

//List name label
struct TaskListNameLabel: View {
    
    //Parameters
    let list: TaskList
    
    @Environment(\.enableListEdit) var enableListEdit
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        Button {
            ListEditObserver.shared.selectedList = list
        } label: {
            Text(list.name)
        }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) // Keeps the appearance like a plain label
        .contextMenu {
            if enableListEdit {
                
                //Edit button
                Button {
                    ListEditObserver.shared.editList = list
                } label: {
                    Label("Edit", systemImage: "gear")
                }
                
                //Promote button
                Button {
                    //Set the list's parent to the parent of its current parent
                    list.parentList = list.parentList?.parentList
                } label: {
                    Label("Promote", systemImage: "arrowshape.up.circle")
                }
                
                //Set root list button
                Button {
                    list.parentList = nil
                } label: {
                    Label("Set as root list", systemImage: "list.bullet.below.rectangle")
                }
                
                //Delete button
                Button(role: .destructive) {
                    ListEditObserver.shared.deleteList = list
                } label: {
                    Label("Delete", systemImage: "xmark")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


//Observable singleton
@Observable
class ListEditObserver {
    var selectedList: TaskList?
    var editList: TaskList?
    var deleteList: TaskList?

    static let shared = ListEditObserver()
    
    private init() {}
}

//Data container
@MainActor class DataContainer {
    let schemaModels = Schema([ TaskList.self ])
    let dataConfiguration: ModelConfiguration
    
    static let preview = DataContainer(memoryDB: false)
    
    init(memoryDB: Bool = false) {
        dataConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: memoryDB)
    }
    
    lazy var dataContainer: ModelContainer = {
        do {
            let container = try ModelContainer(for: schemaModels)
            // seedData(context: container.mainContext)
            return container
        } catch {
            fatalError("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }()
    
    func resetData(context: ModelContext) {
        do {
            // Fetch all TaskList entries
            let lists = try context.fetch(FetchDescriptor<TaskList>())
            
            // Delete each entry
            for list in lists {
                context.delete(list)
            }
            
            // Save changes to persist deletions
            try context.save()
            
            // Re-insert sample data
            withAnimation {
                TaskList.insertSampleData(context: context)
            }
            
            try context.save()
            
        } catch {
            print("Failed to save: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
    }
}

//Environment keys
struct EnableListEditKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Bool = true
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var enableListEdit: Bool {
        get { self[EnableListEditKey.self] }
        set { self[EnableListEditKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

//App
@main
struct TaskListTestApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TaskListContentView()
                .modelContext(DataContainer.preview.dataContainer.mainContext)
        }
    }
}

//Previews
#Preview {
    TaskListContentView()
        .modelContext(DataContainer.preview.dataContainer.mainContext)
}


Give it a try and let me know if I can address any specific points in more details.
UPDATE:
I updated the previously provided code to include the following changes:

Added context menu Delete button and associated delete logic
As part of the delete logic, there's a new deleteList property added to the singleton and a couple of functions in the model extension (delete() and children()).
Restructured sample data and revised reset/insert logic for more reliable resetting
Added a couple of context buttons to promote list and set as root to illustrate the simple operation when using only parentList.


Thanks! I will dig in to this and follow up!

I had some time to digest this & run through some tests. Removing the taskLists array isn't a big deal, it's more for me to maintain over time but it's small & seems like a good compromise since it solves my issue. One great upside I had with the array though was that I could delete the parent and cascade that delete down to all children - a desired side-effect for me. I wrote a few tests and I don't see that same  behavior with just a parentList property. With this approach, will I have to loop over and delete all children manually? Thanks for taking the time to  share an alternative!

Quick follow-up on my question. I know that I can delete all records that have a matching parent using delete(model: where:) - it's just an extra bit of state i'll have to manage during my delete operations rather than it being automatic. My question was more specific around whether or not there is an alternative using @Relationship that I could keep this process automatic with SwiftData.

Does @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) not work with parentList? I haven't tried it.

If it doesn't, implementing your own delete may be even more beneficial, because you could give the option of deleting children or not, whereas relying on @Relationship forces deletion of all children.

Ok thanks for the info. One last question, what does the ListObserver give over the view model approach I was using? Is there a pattern for this that I can research?

It's called a singleton pattern, which guarantees that only one instance of a class is instantiated, providing an observable shared state whenever needed. So you can set a value from one view and read, edit or observe it from any other view without passing the object directly (as a parameter). For example, the context menu Edit button sets the editList property, which is observed by the sheet modifier in TaskListContentView that reacts by showing a sheet with the form view.

I updated the code from my answer to include some extra context menu buttons, including the delete logic. Note the simplicity of the code for Promote and Set as root (which is basically the Clear Parent button from the edit view), while keeping the UI reactive to model/properties changes. See the Update section at the bottom for details. I suggest you recopy the entire code and run it.

Thanks again - you would use this pattern instead of passing it down via .environment on the root view?

You're welcome to do your research and understand the differences between the singleton, environment, regular class, etc. As shown, I would use this approach in this particular case, to keep the UI reactive. In my experience, environment variables, depending on the case, are not always as reactive as you'd think. And using a singleton is far more flexible than creating a thousand environment keys - for me at least.
